# how do I use .isalpha() to detect a maths operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to detect what math operator has been used and then assigning that operator to a variable. This is my code:

```
start = "3x - 2 = 11"
op = "+"

for m in start:
  if m.isalpha():
    if m == "-":
      op = m
    if m == "+":
      op = m
    if m == "*":
      op = m
    if m == "/":
      op = m
print(op)
```

However this prints "+", despite there being a "-" in the string start. Does anybody know why it is not printing out "-"? (btw this is python 3)

Comment: The conditions `m.isalpha()` and `m in ('-', '+', '*', '/')` can never both be true because none of the operators are alphanumeric characters. Thus, `op` will retain its originally assigned value of `'+'` no matter what

Comment: Why such an indirect way to check if `m in '-+*/'`?

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that there is a unique operator you could intersect the characters in `start` with the ops:

```
start = "3x - 2 = 11"
ops = set("+-*/")
op = list(set(start) & ops)[0] # op == '-'
```

If there are multiple operations in `start` then `set(start) & ops` would contain all of them (or be empty if there are no ops).

Note that in your example, you are implicitly using `*` since the intended meaning of `3x - 2 = 11` is probably `3*x - 2 = 11`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that, you're checking if the character is alphabet then do something, you can check if the character is not an alphabet or number.

```
op = "+"
for m in start:
  if not m.isalpha() and not m.isdigit():
    if m == "-":
      op = m
    if m == "+":
      op = m
    if m == "*":
      op = m
    if m == "/":
      op = m
    print op
```

**OR** you should rather keep an array of mathematical operators to check if the character is in your array

```
start = "3x - 2 = 11"
op = "+"
ops = ["-", "+", "/", "*"] #can be ("-", "+", "/", "*") or "-+/*" too
for m in start:
  if m in ops:
    if m == "-":
      op = m
    if m == "+":
      op = m
    if m == "*":
      op = m
    if m == "/":
      op = m
    print op
```